# c# Windows Form, search for string in file based on user input, return whole line

Tags: c#, string, file, search, windows-forms-designer

let's say I have a .txt file containing the following:

> SOFT152, Software Engineering, 20, S1, 0, 0, 0.3, 55, 0.7, 65
>
> SOFT155, Immersive Introduction, 20, S1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 92
>
> NET103, Principles of Infrastructure, 20, S2, 0, 0, 0.5, 70, 0.5, 80
>
> SOFT 153, Principles of Programming Structures & Algorithims, 20, S2, 0.4, 56, 0, 0, 0.6, 75
>
> ISAD 151, Database Development, 20, S1, 0.4, 60, 0, 0, 0.6, 92
>
> MATH160PP, The Quantum Universe, 20, S1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 84

How can I search for a specific string within those lines, based on what a user has written in a textbox and pressed a button (for example) "Find".

Then return the entire line and put each variable in textboxes (which the user could then edit any of the values, etc) like this:

[image]

I've managed to do it using this code, which gives the output how I want it, however I don't know how to change 'string citation' based on user input:

```
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                string citation = "SOFT155";

                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

                    lineFromFile = reader.ReadLine();

                    List<string> matchedList = new List<string>();

                    string[] linesArr = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

                    //find matches
                    foreach (string s in linesArr)
                    {
                        if (s.Contains(citation))
                        {
                            matchedList.Add(s); //matched
                        }
                    }

                    //output
                    foreach (string s in matchedList)
                    {
                        string citationLine = s;
                        string[] lineData = citationLine.Split(',');
                        programmeNameLabel.Text = lineData[0];
                        stageNumberLabel.Text = lineData[1];
                        selectedModuleLabel.Text = lineData[2];
                        moduleTitleTextBox.Text = lineData[3];
                        creditsTextBox.Text = lineData[4];
                        semesterTextBox.Text = lineData[5];
                        examWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[6];
                        examMarkTextBox.Text = lineData[7];
                        testWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[8];
                        testMarkTextBox.Text = lineData[9];
                        courseworkWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[10];
                        courseworkMarkTexbox.Text = lineData[11];
                    }
                }
```

*EDIT 1*

I've managed to get it working.
I added the 'citation' field to the form (Thanks Jakub) and I changed the code, firstly moving it away from the LoadFile() method, and made this:

```
    private void editModuleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        citation = editModuleComboBox.Text;

        citationChange();
    }

    private void citationChange()
    {
        List<string> matchedList = new List<string>();

        string[] linesArr = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

        //find matches
        foreach (string s in linesArr)
        {
            if (s.Contains(citation))
            {
                matchedList.Add(s); //matched
            }
        }

        //output
        foreach (string s in matchedList)
        {
            string citationLine = s;
            string[] lineData = citationLine.Split(',');
            selectedModuleLabel.Text = lineData[2];
            moduleTitleTextBox.Text = lineData[3];
            creditsTextBox.Text = lineData[4];
            semesterTextBox.Text = lineData[5];
            examWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[6];
            examMarkTextBox.Text = lineData[7];
            testWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[8];
            testMarkTextBox.Text = lineData[9];
            courseworkWeightingTextBox.Text = lineData[10];
            courseworkMarkTexbox.Text = lineData[11];
        }
    }
```

This works fine and does what I want it to do. However, using this code (which I put in the LoadFile method, to make it run when file is opened) for the combo box to only show module code. It shows them, but then repeats by how many lines there are (I think so, since I had similar issue earlier, but with textbox that shows file content):

```
                    string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
                    foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
                    {
                        string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
                        editModuleComboBox.Items.Add(tokens[2]);
                        deleteModuleComboBox.Items.Add(tokens[2]);
                    }
```

This is what it looks like in the app while running:

[image]

Thanks everyone

Comment: `string citation = textBoxSearchInput.Text;` ?

Comment: I've tried that however, because I want it after button press, I don't know how to get the 'string citation' to be accessible inside of (for example) "editModuleButton_Click"

Comment: You can make it a field of the form or a property instead of a local variable and then access it from both places.

Comment: There are so many tutorials out there on how to do this, I don't get why you had to address this here?

Comment: A small suggestion - you likely don't want to call `ReadAllLines` twice.

Comment: @Dr4ken: You can create a variable called `citation` in your `editModuleButton_Click` method.  If you've tried something, show what you've tried and explain how it isn't working.  Currently all you're asking is how to get user input, and the first comment above is how you do that.

Comment: I've updated the question, added new code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As David suggested, use a textbox:

```
string citation = textBoxCitation.Text;
```

PS: This is constructive critizise: you've declared some variables that you aren't using. Also, your last foreach is useless, because no matter how big "matchedList" is, your program will display only the last result. There are more things you could do to make your code better, but I think the last foreach is the easier to start with.